# Nokogiri - Check if the link has been added to database if so, go to next link

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, nokogiri

In my application I'm using `Nokogiri` to fetch the first link from *exmple.com* & based on this link it finds *page title* & *image* & adds it to the database.

*This is how I do it currently (this will run every hour):*

```
def nokogiri_link
  # This finds the first link
  website_url = ["http://www.example.com/news/", "http://www.sec-example.com/viral/", "http://www.fun-example.com/fun/"].sample
  doc_website = Nokogiri::HTML(open(website_url), nil, 'UTF-8')
  first_anchor = doc_website.at_css('.article_link').first

  # This finds title and image from first links page
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(first_anchor[1]), nil, 'UTF-8')

  title = ""
  image_url = ""

  doc.xpath("//head//meta").each do |meta|
    if meta['property'] == 'og:title'
      title = meta['content']
    elsif meta['property'] == 'og:image'
      image_url = meta['content']
    end
  end

  @image_link = image_url
  @link = first_anchor[1]
  @title = title
end
```

This works fine for now, but often the sites that I fetch link from doesn't update links every hour, so what I wanna achieve is, when a website has been selected *(randomly)* from `website_url` *array* and it tries to find the fist link, if the `title` exist in my `posts` table, it needs to select another link from `website_url` *array* and try to select its first link.

Comment: what should this method return? or does it just work via side effects (setting instance variables)?

Comment: @maxpleaner thanks for reply. *(I update the last part of the question. appreciate if you take a look at it)*. basically this method setting instance variables `@image_link `, `@link`, `@title`, which I'm using in another part

Answer (score 0):

You can change it so that the method loops over the anchors instead of just using the first one. And put a `next` to go to the next iteration if it's found in the database:

```
def nokogiri_link
  website_url = "http://www.example.com/news/"
  doc_website = Nokogiri::HTML(open(website_url), nil, 'UTF-8')
  doc_website.at_css('.article_link').each do |anchor|
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(anchor[1]), nil, 'UTF-8')
    title = ""
    image_url = ""

    doc.xpath("//head//meta").each do |meta|
      if meta['property'] == 'og:title'
        title = meta['content']
      elsif meta['property'] == 'og:image'
        image_url = meta['content']
      end
    end
    @image_link = image_url
    @link = first_anchor[1]
    @title = title
    unless Post.exists?(title: title)
      Post.create!(title: title)
      break
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch @maxpleaner. This goes to model or controller? does it goes to Model because of `Post.create!`, or?

Comment: when article does not exist, it adds it to the database but for next time, it gives me error: `No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - anchor-class-name`

Comment: I get the above error on:  `doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(anchor[1]), nil, "UTF-8")`

Comment: you need to include some more info about the page you are parsing. What is the value of `doc_website.at_css('.article_link')`?

Comment: Thanks for reply @maxpleaner, Not sure what you mean by value, but if you mean whats the CSS class that I select is `.article_preview--pic`, so it would be: `doc_website.at_css(".article_preview--pic")`. Im trying to test with this link [LifeDaily](http://www.lifedaily.com/category/viral-news/)